# Adding onto an array pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

So I've recently come across something that isn't really intuitive to me and got me a little confused. If I allocate an array on the heap like this:

```
uint32_t* Array = new uint32_t[5];
```

and then try to add a certain amount of bytes to the array pointer like this:

```
Array + 3
```

the result is going to be `Array + sizeof(uint32_t) * 3` instead of `Array + 3`.

Why is this being done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Additive operators (§7.6.6/4) [expr.add]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4):

> When an expression *J* that has integral type is added to or subtracted
>   from an expression *P* of pointer type, the result has the type of *P*.
>
> 1. If *P* evaluates to a *null pointer value* and *J* evaluates to 0, the
>      result is a *null pointer value*.
> 2. Otherwise, if *P* points to element *x[i]* of an array object *x* with *n* elements, the expressions *P + J* and *J + P* (where *J* has the value *j*) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) element  *x[i + j]*  if *0 ≤ i + j ≤ n*  and the expression *P - J* points to the (possibly-hypothetical) element **x[i − j]* if *0 ≤ i − j ≤ n*.
> 3. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

[Subscripting (§7.6.1.1/1) [expr.sub]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sub#1)

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a
>   postfix expression. One of the expressions shall be a glvalue of type
>   “array of T” or a prvalue of type “pointer to T” and the other shall
>   be a prvalue of unscoped enumeration or integral type. The result is
>   of type “T”. The type “T” shall be a completely-defined object type.
>   The expression *E1[E2]* is identical (by definition) to **((E1)+(E2))*,
>   except that in the case of an array operand, the result is an lvalue
>   if that operand is an lvalue and an xvalue otherwise. The expression
>   *E1* is sequenced before the expression *E2*.